# OriginatingServer value different in Get-Mailbox and Get-MailboxStatistics

Tags: powershell, microsoft-office-365, exchangeonline

I am currently working in an Office 365 hybrid environment.
I did a **Get-Mailbox** and **Get-MailboxStatistics** on my own mailbox and discovered that the value of originatingserver is different for each command.

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your mailbox hosted on-premises or in O365?
Since Office 365 is running a huge DAG for Exchange things do move around. Also note that multiple servers in the same virtual Exchange organisation in Office 365 could respond for your mailbox.

Comment: Thanks. Despite the different values of originatingserver, the database names are the same.

Answer (score 0):

The originating server property should be the name of the server that was queried to get the information, it is not a property of the object itself.

In my on-premise Exchange server, it would return DC server name with “`Get-mailbox`”, while Exchange server name with “`Get-MailboxStatistics`”.

Comment: Thanks.  When I was working in Exchange On-premise, I didn't bother to check originatingserver because there was only one Exchange Server.